# Find broken links in python with Selenium. No supplied schema error

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

I'm trying to find broken links in a page. I'm using this code:
(I'm not posing the original URL and element ID data because it's confidential information, and I'm using an explicit wait because it requires a login prior accessing to the page)

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path='C:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://pagename.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 
'elementID')))
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
for link in links:
    r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
    print(link.get_attribute('href'), r.status_code)
```

The thing is this code works for most pages. But the page I'm working with doesn't have the full URL in the href, it only has the '/extension'. So i get the 
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None? error, and I'm having truble with joining the URL with the href. How do I join the URL with the href in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
r = requests.head("https://pagename.com/"+link.get_attribute('href'));
print(("https://pagename.com/"+link.get_attribute('href')), r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

"+" concatenation operator can work.

```
baseURL = "https://domainName.com/resource/" 
for link in links:
r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
actualURL=baseURL + link.get_attribute('href')
```